# List<IFormFile> files gets nothing from dropzone post mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, dropzone.js, dropzone, iformfile

I'm trying to send images from dropzone to my controller mvc project by httpPost

The forms are calling correctly the IActionResult but the files count are always 0

When the forms load I get
[image]

but I'm already giving a URL. Don't know what's the error.

Here is my cshtml script of dropzone config

```
@section Scripts
{

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/basic.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/dropzone.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/dropzone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/dropzone-amd-module.js"></script>
<script>

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myDropzone').dropzone({
            url:"/Aprovacoes/SaveUploadedFile",
            method: "post",
            //parameter name value
            paramName: function () { "files" },
            //clickable div id
            clickable: '#previews',
            //preview files container Id
            previewsContainer: "#previews",
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            maxFiles: 100,
            //  url:"/", // url here to save file
            maxFilesize: 100,//max file size in MB,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            dictResponseError: 'Server not Configured',
            acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg,.pdf",// use this to restrict file type
            init: function () {
                var self = this;
                // config
                self.options.addRemoveLinks = true;
                self.options.dictRemoveFile = "Delete";
                //New file added
                self.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                    console.log('new file added ', file);
                    $('.dz-success-mark').hide();
                    $('.dz-error-mark').hide();
                });
                // Send file starts
                self.on("sending", function (file) {
                    console.log('upload started', file);
                    $('.meter').show();
                });

                // File upload Progress
                self.on("totaluploadprogress", function (progress) {
                    console.log("progress ", progress);
                    $('.roller').width(progress + '%');
                });

                self.on("queuecomplete", function (progress) {
                    $('.meter').delay(999).slideUp(999);
                });

                // On removing file
                self.on("removedfile", function (file) {
                    console.log(file);
                });

                $('#Submit').on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    // Validate form here if needed

                    if (self.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
                        self.processQueue();
                    } else {
                        self.uploadFiles([]);
                        $('#myDropzone').submit();
                    }
                });
                self.on("successmultiple", function (files, response) {
                    // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
                    // Redirect user or notify of success.
                });
            }
        });
    })

</script>
```

And here is the form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveUploadedFile", "Aprovacoes", FormMethod.Post, new { @name = "myDropzone", id = "myDropzone", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

<br />

<div>
    <div id="previews" class="dz-default dz-message box__input dropzone">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" style="font-size:23px;position:relative;top:4px;"></i> <span style="margin-left:20px">Drop files  to attach or browse</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div>
    <input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success m-t-5" value="Submit" />
</div>
}
```

My controller httpPost method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveUploadedFile(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

always come 0

[image]

Comment: I'm using this example [link](https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp.net/file-uploading-using-dropzone-js-html5-in-mvc/81), but was needed some alterations on the HttpPostedFileBase receive method

Comment: This is html form problem when you are trying to upload multiple files at one time with dropzone. Let me know if you have already found solution to your problem. if not I will try to help you.

Comment: @Adlorem I was suspecting that, but I still don't have a solution. I'll appreciate your Help pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my working solution:

View Part

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnBegin = "OnBegin", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }, new { @id = "ajaxForm", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="col-md-12 dropzone">
                        <div class="dropzone-previews" id="dropzonePreview">
                            <i class="icon-file-upload icon-5x absolute-center text-muted"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group mt-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input class="btn btn-inverse btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" name="inputSubmit" type="submit" value="Save" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

Script Part

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var options = {
    paramName: "PhotoFiles",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    autoDiscover: false,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    thumbnailWidth: 250,
    thumbnailHeight: 250,
    dictRemoveFile: 'Delete',
    previewsContainer: '#dropzonePreview',
    clickable: '.dropzone',
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png",
};

    var dropZone = new Dropzone("form#ajaxForm", options);

    dropZone.element.querySelector("input[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        // if dropzone has file process them, if not send empty array
        if (dropZone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
            dropZone.processQueue();
        } else {
            $("#ajaxForm").submit();
        }
    });

    dropZone.on("successmultiple", function (files, response) {
        // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
        // Redirect user or notify of success.
        OnSuccess(response);
    });
    dropZone.on("errormultiple", function (files, response) {
        // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
        // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
        OnFailure(response);
    });
```

Controller Part

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult InsertPhotos()
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                //process files
            }
        }

        //return some result
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me.
The 'Request.Files.Count' on my project is the IformFile, apparently, the IforFile is a newer version, and the MVC 5 only recognizes him.

And I had some trouble with Ajax form, so I changed a bit the @using for just directly using the HTML attributes, it compiled just fine but the IformFIle still getting null.

Your code give me some light on the problem, I think it must be an input name problem, But I don't know how to check it.

Thanks so much for this code.

Comment: You are using MVC Core. In this case should be Request.Form.Files.Count

Comment: It worked, thank you so much, the json result did get the file.
And thanks for the MVC core tip, I was a bit in doubt about that  too

Comment: Glad I could help. Have a nice day.